# output amount from csv file does not in the right format

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Some of the output result on the Transaction amount column is not correct. 
This is the csv file:

```
Account number (preferred / formatted),Customer reference,Posting date,Account currency,Transaction amount
750856653,233454,1/10/2019,USD,-1888.81
750856653,233464,1/10/2019,USD,-873.49
750856653,NONREF,1/10/2019,USD,2762.3
750856653,NONREF,2/10/2019,USD,-456.53
750856653,233467,2/10/2019,USD,-2547.7
```

This is my awk script :

```
Account number (preferred / formatted),Customer reference,Posting date,Account currency,Transaction amount
750-85665-3      0000233454 100119000000188881
750-85665-3      0000233464 100119000000087349
750-85665-3      0000233467 100219000000025477
```

The Amount which was USD, -2547.7 was reformatted to 25477 which is not correct, it should be 254770.
i will like every amount with a single digit after the decimal point to have a Zero(0) at the end, this way it matches the check amount when it is logged into the system.

```
awk -v s1="      " '
BEGIN{
   FS=","
}
FNR==1{
   print
   next
}
$2!~/NONREF/{
   $1=substr($1,1,3)"-"substr($1,4,5)"-"substr($1,length($1))
   $2=sprintf("%010d",$2)
   split($3,array,"/")
   $3=sprintf("%02d%02d%s",array[2],array[1],substr(array[3],3))
   gsub(/^-|\./,"",$NF)
   $NF=sprintf("%012d",$NF)
   $3=$3 $NF
   print $1 s1 $2,$3
}
'  Input_file
```

This my output after the script is ran:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -v s1="      " '
BEGIN{
 FS=","
}
{
  gsub(/\r/,"")
}
FNR==1{
  print
  next
}
$2!~/NONREF/{
  $1=substr($1,1,3)"-"substr($1,4,5)"-"substr($1,length($1))
  $2=sprintf("%010d",$2)
  split($3,array,"/")  
  $3=sprintf("%02d%02d%s",array[2],array[1],substr(array[3],3))
  if($NF~/\.[0-9]$/){
    $NF=$NF"0"
  }
  gsub(/^-|\./,"",$NF)
  $NF=sprintf("%012d",$NF)
  $3=$3 $NF
  print $1 s1 $2,$3
}
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Account number (preferred / formatted),Customer reference,Posting date,Account currency,Transaction amount
750-85665-3      0000233454 100119000001888810
750-85665-3      0000233464 100119000000873490
750-85665-3      0000233467 100219000000254770
```

Comment: @jaybiano, Your welcome, request you to please always keep your codes formatting proper else it is difficult to read. I have fixed it in your post now.

Answer (score 2):

The `awk` script filter out leading `-` and ALL '.' from the last column (amount) with

```
 gsub(/^-|\./,"",$NF)
```

Which will result in decimal numbers scaling up, and loss of sign. You might want to review this command, at least keep the decimals. The decimal portion will be stripped by the `sprintf` command because of the 'd' format. Unlike "C" programs awk will convert the any numeric value (int, float) as needed to match the format.